# How to install librsvg2?

Tags: installation, command-line, apt

How do you install `libsrvg2` with the `apt-get install` command? I've tried the following:

```
root@ubuserver:~# apt-get install librsvg2-bin
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Couldn't find package librsvg2-bin
```

How would you install it?

Comment: how about accepting an answer if one of them worked, or otherwise adding a comment to explain if you're still stuck.

Answer (score 7):

If you've never run an package list update on the server, `apt` might not be able to see the package. The following should work:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install librsvg2-bin
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to find it if exists with this name or different name?

```
apt-cache search librsvg2-bin
```