# How to install rsvg-view in Ubuntu 20?

Tags: snap, libraries, svg

I know that I should [install librsvg2-bin](https://askubuntu.com/questions/31435/how-to-install-librsvg2)

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install librsvg2-bin
```

but after that :

```
rsvg-view-3
rsvg-view-3: command not found
```

so it not works. So I look for the command:

```
locate rsvg-view-3
/snap/gnome-3-34-1804/36/usr/bin/rsvg-view-3
/snap/gnome-3-34-1804/60/usr/bin/rsvg-view-3

find rsvg-view-3
find: ‘rsvg-view-3’: No such file or directory
```

Using snap :

```
snap list
Name                             Version                     Rev    Tracking         Publisher     Notes
acrordrdc                        2018.011.20063              8      latest/stable    mmtrt         -
canonical-livepatch              9.5.5                       95     latest/stable    canonical✓    -
chromium                         86.0.4240.183               1382   latest/stable    canonical✓    -
core                             16-2.47.1                   10185  latest/stable    canonical✓    core
core18                           20200929                    1932   latest/stable    canonical✓    base
emacs                            27.1                        857    latest/stable    alexmurray    classic
gimp                             2.10.20                     297    latest/stable    snapcrafters  -
gnome-3-28-1804                  3.28.0-19-g98f9e67.98f9e67  145    latest/stable    canonical✓    -
gnome-3-34-1804                  0+git.3556cb3               60     latest/stable/…  canonical✓    -
gtk-common-themes                0.1-36-gc75f853             1506   latest/stable/…  canonical✓    -
kde-frameworks-5-core18          5.61.0                      32     latest/stable    kde✓          -
kde-frameworks-5-qt-5-14-core18  5.68.0                      4      latest/stable    kde✓          -
krita                            4.4.1                       61     latest/stable    krita✓        -
okular                           20.04.0                     98     latest/stable    kde✓          -
snap-store                       3.36.0-82-g80486d0          481    latest/stable/…  canonical✓    -
snapd                            2.47.1                      9721   latest/stable    canonical✓    snapd
vlc                              3.0.11                      1700   latest/stable    videolan✓     -
wine-platform-3-stable           3.0.4                       6      latest/stable    mmtrt         -
wine-platform-runtime            v1.0                        183    latest/stable    mmtrt         -
wxmaxima                         17.07.0~git                 164    latest/edge      peterpall     -
```

I can use it :

```
/snap/gnome-3-34-1804/60/usr/bin/rsvg-view-3
```

Whats going on ?

Comment: Seems to be removed from modern 20.04 LTS version. Check the search at https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=bionic&arch=any&mode=filename&searchon=contents&keywords=rsvg-view .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stop building rsvg-view-3. It has been removed upstream and will not
be included in librsvg 2.45.x. The upstream developer of librsvg
suggests eog as a better interactive GUI SVG viewer; display(1) from
ImageMagick is another possibility.*

https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/20.04/ubuntu-universe-arm64/librsvg2-bin_2.48.2-1_arm64.deb.html